# Can't get @Singleton to do anything

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, singleton, jboss7.x, cdi

Running on JBoss AS7, I have this:

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class Connections {
    private final List<AtmosphereResource> connections = new ArrayList<AtmosphereResource>();

    public void add(AtmosphereResource event) {
        connections.add(event);
    }
}
```

and this:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class PubSubAtmosphereHandler extends AbstractReflectorAtmosphereHandler {
    @Inject
    private Connections connections;

    @Override
    public void onRequest(AtmosphereResource event) throws IOException {
        [...]
        connections.add(event); // <---
}
```

NPE on the designate line. After reading countless pages and examples, this is one of the ways that is repeated dozens of times, yet it doesn't work. I have the empty beans.xml, placed in my WEB-INF. What am I missing here ?

Comment: is pubsubhandler managed by the container?

Comment: Are you asking if it is decorated with @ManagedBean ? If so, I tried both with and without to no avail. If you mean something else, you have to elaborate a bit.

Comment: how is it instanciated? what does the code invoking onrequest look like?

Comment: I'm not sure, that happens inside the Atmosphere library. I only specify that class in the atmosphere.xml, and then requests come in. For what it's worth, the original request is a GET http request that opens a comet/websocket connection, and this class is the one that accepts that request and files it away for later server pushes.

Comment: problem is likely that the handler is not contaner managed, so iinjections will not happen.

Comment: Is there a way to get around that ? I don't mind having a proxy class of some sort. Or is the form of the initial instantiation of the handler like the poisonous tree where everything I do from there suffers from the same problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, it turns out that Atmosphere provides (currently broken) hooks for this kind of functionality. That means it **IS** possible to simply use your normal annotations and have it work with Atmosphere, despite the 'foreign' instantiation.

If you know where your code will be deployed, you can simply overwrite the default noop InjectorProvider class from Atmosphere by having a class with the same name in the same package and having it provide the proper Injector.

I am adding code for JBoss AS7 at the end of this answer, as well as links to code that is supposed to work on Google Guice and Spring, which I have not tested myself.

If you need your code to work on multiple platforms, you will probably need to figure out how to detect what you are running on and then return the appropriate Injector. Since I'm not very familiar with Guice and Spring, I'll leave that exercise to the reader.

Dirty 'first draft' code for JBoss AS7 (remember that this has to go into the declared package to overwrite the default noop provider):

```
package org.atmosphere.di;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;

import javax.enterprise.context.spi.CreationalContext;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionTarget;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class InjectorProvider {

    private InjectorProvider() {}

    public static Injector getInjector() {
        return LazyProvider.INJECTOR;
    }

    private static final class LazyProvider {
        private static final Injector   INJECTOR;

        static {
            Injector injector = new Injector() {
                @Override public void inject(final Object o) {
                    try {
                        final BeanManager bm = (BeanManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
                        final CreationalContext cc = bm.createCreationalContext(null);
                        final InjectionTarget it = bm.createInjectionTarget(bm.createAnnotatedType(o.getClass()));
                        it.inject(o, cc);
                        cc.release();
                    } catch (final NamingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            try {
                injector = ServiceLoader.load(Injector.class).iterator().next();
            } catch (final NoSuchElementException e) {}
            INJECTOR = injector;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that the wrapping code is taken from the Atmosphere code base, and is a very bad way to do Singletons in Java. You probably don't want to use this 'as is' in production.

Guice injector, untested: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/blob/atmosphere-1.0.x/extras/guice/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/guice/GuiceInjector.java

Spring injector, untested: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/blob/atmosphere-1.0.x/extras/spring/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/spring/SpringInjector.java

Comment: This solution probably works with specific atmosphere version? Because I checked, current atmosphere does not have org.atmosphere.di package.

Comment: As the original problem occurred back in 2013, I couldn't tell you where Atmosphere developed towards since then. At the writing, support for this was very bare bones and as mentioned had a bug that made it not work at all out of the box. Since DI frameworks if anything have gained in popularity, I am certain that this day and age, there are better solutions available out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

What others are trying to say is that the lifecycle of the PubSubAtmosphereHandler must be controlled by the container (aka JBoss).

In other words the container is responsible for creating and initialising instances of PubSubAtmosphereHandler.

If you or your framework creates this object then the injections will not take place.

Comment: So does that mean that the Atmosphere framework is fundamentally incapable of being used with injections ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to get BeanManager using jndi. Then you can get the bean from there.

```
BeanManager bm = initialContext.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
Bean<Connections> bean = (Bean<Connections>) bm.getBeans(Connections.class).iterator().next();
CreationalContext<Connections> ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);

Connections connections = (Connections) bm.getReference(bean, Connections.class, ctx);
connections.add(event);
```

Comment: How do you suggest to get `initialContext` here? Maybe `BeanManager` can also be accessed using this code? `BeanManager bm = CDI.current().getBeanManager();`